# PHP does not connect to localhost MongoDB and fails silently

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a PHP script like this:

```
try {
    $conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var_dump($conn);
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

When I visited the page, it showed nothing. mongod shows no connection attempt, but shell client works normally.

I'm running MongoDB 2.4 on Debian.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try loop-back IP address there instead of localhost , `127.0.0.1` most of the time or check in your `hosts` file

Comment: Figured out that finally. Forgotten to add the mongodb extension. Thanks for your help anyway : )